# How to control styling of a dynamic html table of a static html page through App.config file in a c# console application?

Tags: c#, html, app-config

I've been trying to do something. I have a console application which looks for some files, if they exist or not. Accordingly this application sends an email to my email-id. A normal SuccessBody.html is created for an e-mail format.

Now, I'm trying to add a html table dynamically in message.html like below.

HTML

```
<body>
    Hi All,
    <br />
    <br />
    Please be informed that below files for this month <b>are available</b>.
    <br />
    <br />
    <table align="center" ; width="1000" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-color:#17202A; text-align:center;">
        <tr height="30" ; style="background-color:#CED8F6; color:#17202A; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;">
            <td colspan="2" ; style=" border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid; border-width:thick; padding: 5px;">$Title$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:#143665; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;">$Columns$</tr>
        $Rows$
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <b>Please take necessary actions.</b>
    <br />
    <br />
    Regards,
    <br />
    Ricky
</body>
```

I don't want to do the designing of this table in the code itself, but through Config file. And the crucial part is the designing while looping.
The $Title$, $Column$, and $Rows$ are the strings which I want to replace by some code in c# shown below:

C#

```
public static void DataTableToHTML(DataTable Entries)
        {
            string mailbody = string.Empty;
            if (Entries.Rows.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                string email_body_error = File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body_Fail"]);
                mailbody = email_body_error;
            }
            else
            {
                string email_body_success = string.Empty;
                string html = string.Empty;
                TextWriter writehtmlFile = new StreamWriter(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName) + ".html");
                string ConfigTitle = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Title"];
                File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body_Success"]).Replace("$Title$", ConfigTitle);
                for (int i = 0; i < Entries.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    html += ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ForColumns"] + Entries.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</td>";
                }
                File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body_Success"]).Replace("$Columns$", html);
                //add rows
                for (int i = 0; i < Entries.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    html += ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ForRows"];
                    for (int j = 0; j < Entries.Columns.Count; j++)
                        html += ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RowData"] + Entries.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                }
                writehtmlFile.WriteLine(html);
                writehtmlFile.Flush();
                writehtmlFile.Close();
                email_body_success = File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body_Success"]).Replace("$Rows$", html);

                mailbody = email_body_success;
            }
            SendEmail(mailbody, DateTime.Now);
        }
```

I want to configure the settings of this table in Config file (AppConfig.xml) and use it in the above code from there.

Config file

```
<add key="FileName" value="File Name"/>
    <add key="Date" value="Creation Date"/>
    <add key ="ForColumns" value="&lt;td style=\&quot; border-color:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid; border-width:thick; padding: 5px;\&quot;&gt;"/>
    <add key="ForRows" value="&lt;tr style =\&quot;color:#17202A; font-weight:bold; font-family: Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;\&quot; &gt;"/>
    <add key="RowData" value="&lt;td style=\&quot; border-color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#F3E2A9; border-style:solid; border-width:thick; padding: 5px;\&quot;&gt;"/>
    <add key="Body_Success" value="HTMLBody\SuccessBody.html"/>
```

Body_Success is the location of SuccessBody.html = App's location.

$Title$ got replaced easily. But, $Column$, and $Rows$ are not getting replaced as I want them to. If anyone could help me, that would be really great.

Comment: [`ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1) returns a string. You don't store that at all. IIRC the compiler warns about that.

Answer (score -1):

```
I would suggest - 
Create html file and save email html part along with keywords which you want to replace like as ForColumns ,ForRows.
e.g. 
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
       <th>ForColumns1 </th>
       <th>ForColumns2 </th>
      </thead>
     <tr>ForRows1</tr>
     <tr>ForRows2</tr>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>


while sending mail get replace keyword(ForColumns,ForRows) value from config and replace with html file data.
```

Answer (score -2):

In .Net (and many other tool stacks) strings are expected to be immutable. This means that once you have done:

```
string foo = "bar";
```

you will always find "bar" if you inspect the var `foo`. If you want `foo` to be something else you have to assign it a new value:

```
string foo = "fubar";
string huh = foo.Replace("fu", "foo");
```

That same principle goes for methods you call on strings, like `Replace`. That method returns a new string where it has your original sting replaced with new values. So in the above example `huh` will have the value "foobar" where `foo` will still be "fubar".

Therefor on this line:

```
File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body_Success"]).Replace("$Title$", ConfigTitle);
```

you're dropping the replaced results on the floor.

Instead do this:

```
// read the template from the file once and put it in a variable
email_body_success = File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body_Success"]);
// replace the title by storing the replaced value again the same variable
email_body_success = email_body_success.Replace("$Title$", ConfigTitle);
```

From this point going forward, `email_body_success` will have the string with the (partially) replaced template. You don't need (and it is wrong to do so) to call `File.ReadAlltext` again. Because if you do, you'll read the template from the file again, throwing away what was already replaced.

Now we come to the two loops, for columns and rows. Once you have build up the stuff you need, the content of `html` needs to be replaced with the marker in `email_body_success`.

Instead of:

```
File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body_Success"]).Replace("$Columns$", html);
```

do

```
// replace the columns
email_body_success = email_body_success.Replace("$Columns$", html);
html = String.Empty; // html is stored, let's reset for its next use.
```

because now `email_body_success` will have our previous partially replaced template with our new html for $Columns$. At the start of your Rows loop, you want to reset the `html` string to empty again so it won't still hold the columns

At the end of the Rows loop the same fix need to be applied. Replace

```
email_body_success = File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Body_Success"]).Replace("$Rows$", html);
```

with

```
 // replace the rows
 email_body_success = email_body_success.Replace("$Rows$", html);
```

That should give you in `email_body_success` the template with its replaced parts.

I'm unsure what you wanted to achieve with this line:

```
writehtmlFile.WriteLine(html);
```

but if you meant to write the whole template to that file, you need to replace `html`with the `email_body_success` variable and move those lines after the last Replace.

Comment: Yeah!. @rene. I was also looking into the code and was thinking that I won't need the streamwriter to write an html file if I'm following this approach. But wasn't sure enough `:).